# How to export non-blurry eps images?

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure

I'm exporting an image in Matlab using the eps format, but it smooths the image. Matlab does not blur the image using other formats such as png. I would like to know how to export a non-blurry image with eps format. Here is the resulting image using png:
[image]

And here is the resulting image using eps:
[image]

Answer (score 11, accepted):

#### UPDATE:

The problem is reproducible on a Mac, and the issue is with the eps renderer rather than MATLAB. For e.g., saving `imagesc(rand(20))` and viewing with Preview and GSview results in the following:

#### Preview screenshot

[image]

#### GSview screenshot

[image]

Clearly, the information is not lost. It is just not interpreted/read correctly by some EPS viewers. The solution is simple: use GSview to view your `eps` images. You can download it from [here](http://pages.cs.wisc.edu/%7Eghost/)

On Macs especially, if your end application is latex/pdflatex, you will have to explicitly set it to use GS/GSview, because otherwise, it will default to the Quartz engine, which is baked into the OS.

---

#### PREVIOUS ANSWER:

I am unable to reproduce the behavior your described. Here is the code I used, tested using R2010b on WinXP 32-bit:

```
M = fspecial('gaussian',[20 20],5);
imagesc(M)
print('-dpng','a.png')
print('-depsc2','b.eps')
```

#### a.png

[image: a.png]

#### b.eps

[image: b.eps]

Perhaps this is an issue with your EPS viewer...

Comment: Great answer, but can you please elucidate how to `explicitly set it to use GS/GSview` for `LaTeX`? I tried googling, but didn't find a way of doing so. Thanks!

Comment: @SibbsGambling: I'm mostly a Windows user, the Mac part of the answer was edited by yoda at the time (who has since changed account to [r.m.](http://stackoverflow.com/users/3730911/r-m) if I'm not mistaken)... I guess what he meant was to associate PDF and EPS files to open with GSView by default instead of the default viewer in OSX (which apparently does some sort of anti-aliasing which explains the blurry looking images). Unlike other OSX apps (Preview, Keynote, ..), GSView seems to have its own rendering engine and apparently does not use the one provided by the system (Quartz).

Comment: I see. Thanks a lot. I only found the `Ghostscript` option in `Distiller`. Is it the right place? If it is the right place, then it is weird, since I have already ticked `Ghostscript ` and unticked `Apple Distiller`, but the .eps is still blurry.

Comment: @Amro In which system did you use to open the files? I think I need to have Ubuntu Linux with GSview in VirtualBox, just for previewing .eps files in OS X El Capitan.

Comment: @Masi actually I'm on Windows where I use any of [GSView](http://pages.cs.wisc.edu/~ghost/gsview/), [SumatraPDF](http://www.sumatrapdfreader.org/), or [Evince](https://wiki.gnome.org/Apps/Evince) to open PostScript files (they also handle PDF). None of them show any blurriness.. Perhaps you can install Evince on OSX (I think it's available in both homebrew and fink). btw the mac part of the answer is not me :)

Comment: @Amro I profiled Evince with my test signals. It loses data in opening .eps files. Do you have more recommendations for .eps viewers?

Comment: @Masi did you try the mac version of GSView as originally suggested (it uses ghostscript as backend)?

Comment: @Amro No. They have servers down so I could not download their images. I instead set up Ubuntu Linux in VirtualBox where I use `gv` directly. I need to have several benchmarks such that I can evaluate each viewer's quality. I try to get some standard built-image of GSView working when they are hosted for OS X.

Answer (score 5):

not sure why it works but you can try doing the following:

```
eps2eps oldfile newfile
```

does the trick for me (on a mac os)

Comment: For me it works as well, on Mac OS X. (All other approaches failed.)

Comment: What is the version of your *psutils*? Here report that not working with 1.23 http://stackoverflow.com/a/35793889/54964

Answer (score 4):

At first I thought you were doing something incorrectly, but then I remembered that this was an issue that was bothering the hell out of me a year or so ago. I couldn't come up with a way to "fix" this behaviour and from what I've researched, this is most likely a bug and several others have had this problem too and there is no known solution. Of course, I could be wrong about the last part and there might be solutions out there that have come out since I looked for them.

Any way, my workaround this problem was to use `pcolor` with `shading flat` instead of `imagesc`. When you export this to an `eps` format it preserves the image correctly. Example:

```
pcolor(rand(20));
shading flat
print('-depsc','figure.eps')
```

[image]

**NOTE:** You *might* see the appearance of thin, faint white lines along the anti-diagonals of each little square (depends on the OS & viewer). These are the edges of the graphics primitives that are used to render the image. However, this is **not** a flaw in MATLAB's export, but rather a fault in rendering in your EPS/PDF viewer. For e.g., with the default settings in Preview on my mac, these lines show up, whereas with the default in Adobe Reader 9.4, they don't appear.

Comment: This works perfectly! No faint white lines appear when using LaTeX's `epstopdf` conversion. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2):

If anyone is still interested in a workaround: Open the .eps-file with text editor and search for "interpolate". You'll probably find "/Interpolate true def" two or three times. Replace "true" with "false" and be happy :)

Comment: Does this work? I thought pdfkit on Mac didn't respect the Interpolate option? Also, in my matlab generated EPS I don't find the interpolate line. Can you give some more details about where it should be inserted?

Comment: I did not find any Interpolate in my eps

Comment: `/Interpolate true` is PDF not EPS.

Answer (score 1):

A note regarding Yoda's answer: in Preview in Mac OS X, you can make the thin white diagonal lines across each of the squares disappear by unchecking "Anti-alias text and screen art". Of course, the downside is that then any text (e.g. figure axes, etc) is not anti-aliased. Unfortunately, unchecking that has no effect on blurriness if you're using imagesc.

Another note is that if you use preview to make a pdf from your eps, the resulting pdf still displays correctly (non-blurry) when you open it in Acrobat.

Comment: Very interesting notice! How can you uncheck *Anti-alias text and screen art* in Preview's Settings? I cannot find it in El Capitan. Do you have any picture what the white diagonal lines look like. I am very interested in seeing their appearance. I opened a new thread about your claim here http://apple.stackexchange.com/q/231745/15504

Answer (score 1):

I've been long struggling with this problem as well. So far, GSView is the only viewer I've found that displays the eps figures produced by Matlab (R2015b) correctly. eps2eps did not work for me (psutils 1.23).
The following eventually worked for me:

1. Export the figure to pdf, following the instructions [here](http://uk.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/12987-how-to-save-a-matlab-graphic-in-a-right-size-pdf)
2. pdf2ps file.pdf file.eps

Comment: Please, do not use `saveas`. It is very buggy in Matlab 2016a. The command `export_fig` is much more robust https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/23629-export-fig

Answer (score 0):

The blurring actually depends on the rendering software your viewer application or printer uses. To get good results all the time, make each pixel in your image an 8x8 block of pixels of the same color, i.e. resize the image like this:

```
im2 = imresize(im1, 8, 'nearest');
```

The blurring then only affects the pixels at the edge of each block. 8x8 blocks are best as they compress without nasty artifacts using DCT compression (sometimes used in eps files).

Answer (score 0):

Apply *opengl* renderer to the figure

```
figure(gcf);
set(gcf,'renderer','opengl');
```

Comment: You should describe more why this works. Or what this all means.

Comment: This only works because by changing the renderer to `opengl` it saves it as a raster-ish EPS rather than a true vector graphic.

Answer (score 0):

I just wrote this simple drop-in replacement for `imagesc`. It doesn't support all but the most basic features, but I still hope it helps.

```
function h = imagesc4pdf(C)

[ny nx] = size(C);

px = bsxfun(@plus, [-0.5; 0.5; 0.5; -0.5], reshape(1:nx, [1 1 nx]));
py = bsxfun(@plus, [-0.5; -0.5; 0.5; 0.5], 1:ny);

n = numel(C);
px = reshape(repmat(px, [1 ny 1]), 4, n);
py = reshape(repmat(py, [1 1 nx]), 4, n);

h = patch(px, py, reshape(C,1,n), 'linestyle', 'none');

xlim([.5 nx+.5]);
ylim([.5 ny+.5]);
set(gca, 'ydir', 'reverse');
```

Comment: Can you please describe what your code is doing? Example output would also be great.

Answer (score 0):

This page helped me a lot: http://tech.mof-mof.co.jp/blog/machine-learning-octave.html (written in Japanese, please use google translate for it)

And this is also helpful: [Octave-Gnuplot-AquaTerm error: set terminal aqua enhanced title "Figure 1"...unknown terminal type"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13786754/octave-gnuplot-aquaterm-error-set-terminal-aqua-enhanced-title-figure-1-unk)

I also answered at https://www.coursera.org/learn/machine-learning/discussions/weeks/2/threads/Dh-aRfqSEeaHSQ6l4xnh6g.

I reinstalled gnuplot like this:

```
$ brew cask install xquartz
$ brew cask install aquaterm
$ brew uninstall gnuplot
$ brew install gnuplot --with-aquaterm --with-x11 --with-qt  # you can show other options by `$ brew options gnuplot`
```

You may edit ~/.octaverc like this:

```
setenv("GNUTERM", "qt")
```

and in octave window, after typing "system gnuplot", then

```
set pm3d interpolate 2, 2
```

After saving the file, open octave-cli.app, and type

```
imagesc(magic(3)), colorbar
```

I got this.

[image]