# Getting rid of interpolation/aliasing in EPS export of matlab?

Tags: matlab, eps

I have a 2D color-map plot created with `imagesc` and want to export it as a `.eps` file using 
`print -depsc`.

The problem is that the "original" image data is from a rather small matrix (131 x 131). When I view the image in the matlab figure window, I can see all the individual pixels if I zoom a bit closer.

When I export to eps, however, there seems to be some interpolation or anti-aliasing going on, in that neighboring pixels get blurred/blended into each other. I don't get the problem if I export a high-resolution tiff, but that format is not an option (as demanded by a publisher).

How can I obtain an eps that preserves the pixely structure of my image without applying interpolation or anti-aliasing?

Comment: can you provide some example code we can test ourselves?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to export non-blurry eps images in Matlab?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6614207/how-to-export-non-blurry-eps-images-in-matlab)

Answer (score 0):

The blurring actually depends on the rendering software your viewer application or printer uses. To get good results all the time, make each pixel in your image an 8x8 block of pixels of the same color. The blurring then only affects the pixels at the edge of each block. 8x8 blocks are best as they compress without nasty artifacts using DCT compression (sometimes used in eps files).

Answer (score 0):

Old question, but highly ranked in Google, so here is my answer:

Open the .eps-file with a text editor, search for "Interpolate" and change the following "true" to "false". Repeat that step for all Interpolate-statements.

It might also depend on the viewer you're using, but probably just because some viewers ignore the "Interpolate"s...

Had the same problem using plot2svg in Matlab and exporting from Inkscape to eps.