# Gnuplot cannot recognize AquaTerm even I have it installed on OSX 10.8.5

Tags: macos, gnuplot, osx-mountain-lion, x11, xterm

I'm trying to install gnuplot on osx 10.8.5 (Mountain Lion), using homebrew.

Here're the steps:

1. download AquaTerm from [sourceforge](http://sourceforge.net/projects/aquaterm/)
2. install gnuplot using homebrew: `brew install gnuplot`

It seems that gnuplot cannot find the installed AquaTerm, because after gnuplot was installed, I have: `Terminal type set to 'unknown'`, although I have terminal type set to aqua.

If I type: `set term` in gnuplot, it returns me a whole list of terminals, but there's no aqua.

Two possible solutions I've found online and tried, but none of them worked for me:

1. I tried to download the [gnuplot source](http://sourceforge.net/projects/gnuplot/postdownload?source=dlp), do local `./configure`, I found that the configuration cannot find AquaTerm because of this in the output: `aqua: no`
2. According to [this post](http://bl.anthonysutardja.com/post/28024250835/mountain-lion-x11-and-gnuplot), I tried to install XQuartz (replacement of X11), and set term to be x11. I then get the error below:

   ```
     Terminal type set to 'x11'
     Options are ' nopersist'
     gnuplot>
     gnuplot: unable to open display ''
     gnuplot: X11 aborted.
   ```

I think the problem I'm having is that.. gnuplot cannot find AquaTerm, therefore cannot using AquaTerm to display; additionally, it somehow conflicts with the XQuartz term here.

I don't know what to do now.. any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Some other methods [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18603167/728291)

Comment: @user728291 Thanks a lot, this method works ;)