# octave for signal processing display

Tags: signals, signal-processing, octave

I'm trying to use octave to process signals for signals & systems lesson. I was trying to display a basic signal with `sig1 = [ ]`, then I'm using `octave:>stem(sig1,’*’)` command, it gives this error:

gnuplot> set terminal aqua enhanced title "Figure 1"  font "*,6" dashlength 1
                      ^
         line 0: unknown or ambiguous terminal type; type just 'set terminal' for a list

I have no idea why it is happening, it should be very simple, but apperently I can't make it.

Thanks for help.

Comment: Duplicate question; see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13786754/octave-gnuplot-aquaterm-error-set-terminal-aqua-enhanced-title-figure-1-unk

Comment: And the answer there by @rehumbus worked for me: `setenv("GNUTERM", "qt")`