# How to import an eps file and insert the image to some position of a figure?

Tags: matlab, plot, eps

I am doing a dimensional reduction experiment and want to demonstrate the human faces in the low-dimensional (2D) space according to the result of the dimensional reduction. My MATLAB script works quite well when the faces are in PNG format. But it doesn't work on EPS files, where at least `imread` cannot recognize EPS format. So how can I do this? Thank you.

Comment: http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/newsreader/view_thread/16314

Comment: Why in the first place do you convert the data to .png images? I think it is most accurate to keep the data in .mat and process that. A thread about just exporting .eps images. Export to .png loses much more pieces of information http://stackoverflow.com/a/6617536/54964

Answer (score 2):

EPS files cannot be read using imread or any other image processing function. What you could do instead (just a suggestion) is

1. Using this code, convert your EPS into PNG first.

   [EPS2XXX](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/6858-eps2xxx)
2. Then, you can do your usual processing using this PNG file. You mentioned you can deal with PNG's. So I am not elaborating in it.

I hope that helps (thanks to the author of the File Exchange Author too).