# MATLAB - Axis equal and meanwhile stretch-to-fill?

Tags: image, matlab, plot, matlab-figure, aspect-ratio

By default, `stretch-to-fill` is on. So

```
pixels = ones(100,100)
image(pixels);
colormap([0 0 0; 1 1 1]);
```

produces

[image]

Forcing the axes to be of the same scale, this

```
pixels = ones(100,100)
image(pixels);
colormap([0 0 0; 1 1 1]);
axis equal;
```

produces

[image]

Obviously, `stretch-to-fill` is overridden by `axis equal`. What to do to make them co-exist?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you are looking for this call:

```
figure(1)
image(pixels)
colormap(clr)
axis image        % <-- this call
```

[image]

Here is a table of the axes properties [manipulated](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/visualize/manipulating-axes-aspect-ratio.html) by the various [`axis`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/axis.html) [modes](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/visualize/understanding-axes-aspect-ratio.html):

[image: axis_modes_axes_props]

---

You can also do something similar using the `imshow` function, which acts as a higher-level wrapper to `image`/`imagesc`:

```
figure(2)
imshow(pixels, clr, 'InitialMag','fit', 'Border','loose')
axis on
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! This pretty much solves my problem. However, why it seems blurred when I try to save it as pdf by `saveas(gcc, file_name, 'pdf');`? [It looks like this.](http://i.stack.imgur.com/9JepL.png)

Comment: @FarticlePilter: are you on a Mac machine? Other people had this issue with the builtin EPS/PDF viewer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/6617536/97160. If that's the case, try a different viewer

Comment: Yes, I am on Mac! Thanks a lot again for the great pointer!! So does this mean that I can safely put the seemingly blurry pdf in my paper? Others will see it good?

Comment: I cant confirm it myself (I'm on a PC), but I think so. You can try opening the PDF in a modern web browser (Firefox for example has a builtin PDF viewer)...

Comment: Good advice! It saves me trouble downloading another PDF viewer!

Answer (score 0):

The problem is, your axis limits reflect the old size. Maybe there is a generic way to solve it, but setting the limits manually solves it:

```
xlim([1,100]);ylim([1,100])
```